# How to read a property only if it exist in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object, where I sometime receive a value, and sometime not.

When I get this value, I can correctly assign it to the object.

I know that using `myObj.hasOwnProperty('myProperty')` I can test if the property exist in a if statement. But when I read it on the line just below (which should happen only if the property is set), I get the following error:

> ERROR in /my/project/my.file.ts (xx,yy): Property 'property' does not exist on type 'type'.

How can I only read the value only if it exist, and thus not get this error ?

```
if (myObj.hasOwnProperty('myProperty')){
    doStuff(myObj.myProperty);
}
```

Comment: declare your object as `myObj: any`, or if you really want it to be `myObj: object`, use `myObj['myProperty']` to retrieve the property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `myObj['myProperty']`

```
if (myObj['myProperty'] !== undefined) {
    // here myProperty is defined (but maybe null or other falsy value)
}
```

As stated in comments, if you can redefined your myObj type then typing it as `any` makes Typescript allow you to try whicherver property you want, then you can simple write :

```
if (myObj.myProperty !== undefined) {
    // here myProperty is defined (but maybe null or other falsy value)
}
```